# DRF Serializer вложенность

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Есть такой сериализатор:

```
class GetUserFriendsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""
Сериализатор, показывающий друзей и их модели
"""

class Meta:
    model = Friend
    fields = ('id', 'created', 'to_user', 'from_user')
    depth = 1
```

Он выдаёт к примеру:

```
{
"id": 1,
"created": "2020-12-29T22:02:01.706917+03:00",
"to_user": {
    "id": 1,
    "password": "pbkdf2_tHw=",
    "username": "admin",
    "email": "g@mail.com",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "gender": "",
    "age": null,
    "about_me": "",
    "location": "",
    "date_joined": "2020-12-28",
    "last_login": "2020-12-30T10:30:14.527528+03:00",
    "is_active": true,
    "is_staff": true,
    "is_superuser": true,
    "groups": [],
    "user_permissions": []
},
```

Как сделать, чтобы он выводил только нужные мне поля в to_user?

ViewSet:

```
class GetUsersFriendsView(ModelViewSet):
"""

"""
serializer_class = GetUserFriendsSerializer
queryset = Friend.objects.all()
permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо сделать отдельный сериализатор для to_user, например так:

```
class ToUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """сериализатор для модели ToUser"""

    class Meta:
        model = ToUserModel
        fields = ('id',
                  'username',
                  'email')


class GetUserFriendsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Сериализатор, показывающий друзей и их модели
    """
    to_user = ToUserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Friend
        fields = ('id', 'created', 'to_user', 'from_user')
        depth = 1
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, верное решение, from_user, to_user = ToUserSerializer, чтобы и 2 получить